# How to use statistics to speed up row-wise computations on a data.frame?

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame with 10,000 rows and 40 columns. I am trying to apply a function to each of these rows. For each row, I am expecting to return a scalar which is the value of the statistic I am calculating in this function. Below is what I have done so far;

```
library(sandwich)

# Creating example data #

nrows=10000
ncols=40
n1=20
n2=20
df=data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# Function to evaluate on each row of df #

get_est= function(x){
mod = lm(x~cov$group)
vcov = vcovHC(mod)
coef = as.numeric(mod$coefficients[2])
se = sqrt(as.numeric(diag(vcov)[2]))
stats = coef/se
return(stats)
}

# Applying above function to full data #

t1=Sys.time()
estimates=apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))
t2=Sys.time()-t1

# Time taken by apply function

Time difference of 32.10623 secs
```

Is there a way to significantly decrease the time taken to implement get_est() on the full data? The main reason I need to speed up the computation on a single df is because I have 1000 more data frames with the same dimension and I have to apply this function to each row to each of these data frames simultaneously. To illustrate, below is the broader situation I am dealing with;

```
# Creating example data

set.seed(1234)
nrows = 10000
ncols = 40
n1 = 20
n2 = 20
df.list = list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  df.list[[i]] = data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
}

# Applying get_est() to each row and to each of data frame in df.list #

all.est = foreach(j = 1:length(df.list), .combine = cbind, .packages = 'sandwich') %dopar% {
  cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))
  est = apply(df.list[[j]], 1, function(x) get_est(x))
  return(est)
}
```

Even after parallelizing it is taking hours to finish. My ultimate objective is to significantly cut down the time to obtain "all.est" which will contain 10000 rows and 1000 columns where each column has the stats estimates for the respective data set. Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: More suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, posted there too!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for an explicit request not to cross-post on SE.

Comment: The answer below about precomputing parts of the results relies on details of the algorithm and requires statistical expertise to derive. Compare this to the answer on SE about parallelizing, which does not and offers relatively little performance improvement, and it is very clear that this question is best answered here. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support @ChrisHaug!! @Nick Cox Thanks for letting me know the guidelines I will definitely keep this in mind before posting anything in future.

Comment: Hi @Capri, I see that you've made an edit to your post which invalidates the answer. This is very harmful to the site! Invalidating an answer means that the people who have spent time and effort to understand and answer your question have their work negated. When you realize that your question is not exactly what you wanted to know, you should instead **ask a new question** which is clear and specific to your problem. I'm going to roll back your edit so that your question is stated in its original form, and Ben's answer is responsive. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `get_est` uses some "expensive" functions, such as `lm`, `vcovHC`, and so on. If you think of the OLS equation,

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty,
$$

then you can see that the first part $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ doesn't change in your simulation, so the design matrix is constant. To make use of this, I compute $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ before starting the simulation. This approach then also requires computing the HC3 standard errors manually using the formula (see e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2FBF03192961.pdf))

$$
\widehat{\text{Cov}}_{\text{HC3}}(\hat{\beta}) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T \text{diag} \left[ \frac{e_i^2}{(1-h_{ii})^2} \right] X(X^TX)^{-1}.
$$

Everything except for the residuals is constant across your simulation iterations, so it can be precomputed. Once I implement these tricks, I achieve a speed up of roughly factor 50.

(Note: `lm` uses QR decomposition, which could also be implement similarly here. Maybe you can an ever bigger speed up by parallelizing the code.)

```r
nrows = 10000
ncols = 40
n1 = 20
n2 = 20
df = data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov = data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# old function
get_est_old = function(x){
  mod = lm(x~cov$group)
  vcov = sandwich::vcovHC(mod)
  coef = as.numeric(mod$coefficients[2])
  se = sqrt(as.numeric(diag(vcov)[2]))
  stats = coef/se
  return(stats)
}

# new function
# first construct design matrix
X = matrix(c(rep(1, ncols), rep(0, ncols / 2), rep(1, ncols / 2)), ncol = 2)
# these quantities will be used below
inv = solve(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X)
h = diag(X %*% inv)

get_est_new= function(x){
  coef = (inv %*% x)
  resid = x - (X %*% coef)
  bread = (resid^2 / (1 - h)^2)[,1]
  hc3 = inv %*% diag(bread) %*% t(inv)
  se = sqrt(hc3[2,2])
  stats = coef[2,1]/sqrt(hc3[2,2])
}

# Applying above function to full data #

system.time({
  estimates_old = apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est_old(x))  
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   7.876   0.042   7.929

system.time({
estimates_new = apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est_new(x))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.141   0.016   0.158

# check
all.equal(estimates_old, estimates_new)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

These posts could be of interest:

- https://grantmcdermott.com/efficient-simulations-in-r/
- https://grantmcdermott.com/simulations-remix-turn-up-the-base/

Comment: Thanks! This trick does help!! Quick thing.. If I replace the "lm" function with "rlm (robust linear models)" from library MASS can you please suggest what additional changes I need to make to your code above since its based on lm?

Comment: From the documentation, it sounds like rlm is based on an iterative algorithm, so precomputing parts of the solution won't work for that.

Comment: Thanks @Ben! I have edited my question so that anyone answering will now know that I am working with rlm and not lm. In case you figure a way out with rlm please do update it here.

Comment: I doubt that many will feel inclined to answer if you change the question afterwards.

Comment: Hi @Ben, I've rolled back OP's edit so that your (very good!) answer remains responsive, and left a comment to OP explaining why. I've also edited your answer to remove the disclaimer at the top.